# How to recover an AHCI / legacy conflict in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, ahci

Motherboard: "EVGA E762 X58 Classified 4-WAY SLI"
OS: Windows 7 Pro (64)

I bought a used processor on ebay, and while trying to get it to POST, I cleared BIOS settings, forgetting a crucial idiosyncratic issue about this motherboard. AHCI mode is not enabled by default, however it when Windows was initially installed, it had been set to AHCI MODE.

Clearing BIOS returned that setting to default, which was legacy mode, and thus booting the computer the next time prompted HAL to attempt to adapt to this new interface mode, which failed.

Neither safemode nor "last known good configuration" are solutions, even after reverting the BIOS changes back to AHCI.

What means can be taken to repair this Windows install?

Thanks

Comment: “Clearing BIOS returned that setting to default, which was legacy mode” - What does legacy or compatibility mode which controls if your using MBR or UEFI have to do with the ACHI SATA mode?

Comment: @Ramhound My motherboard doesn't have UEFI, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You should edit your question.  Your use of “legacy mode” is confusing

Comment: "Legacy mode" is what this boot option is called in the BIOS on many systems.